# Video background in flutter

Tags: video, background, dart, flutter

It is possible to have a background video playing all time in flutter?

i was looking for some packages and trying to make it function but i dont know how.

maybe using something like this but with video.

```
decoration: new BoxDecoration(

    image: new DecorationImage(
    image: new AssetImage("images/f1.jpg"),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
),),
```

inside a container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player the example provided is pretty straight forward to follow. You can then just place the video widget inside a Stack layout with your content displayed overlayed - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html Any feature request you can email the creator via the github link

Answer (score 15):

A solution which handles overflow using a FittedBox widget:

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox.expand(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: _controller.value.size?.width ?? 0,
          height: _controller.value.size?.height ?? 0,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    LoginWidget()
  ],
)
```

A full example would be:

```dart
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(BackgroundVideo());

class BackgroundVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BackgroundVideoState createState() => _BackgroundVideoState();
}

class _BackgroundVideoState extends State<BackgroundVideo> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'http://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _controller.play();
        _controller.setLooping(true);
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox.expand(
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: _controller.value.size?.width ?? 0,
                  height: _controller.value.size?.height ?? 0,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            LoginWidget()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}

class LoginWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          width: 300,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.grey.withAlpha(200),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Username',
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Login'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The `dispose()` method which contains `_controller.dispose();` is super important otherwise the app will be having a memory leak which will crash it. Thanks for the full answer +1.