# Video widget doesn't play "Unable to establish connection on channel"

Tags: flutter

Hello I've been trying to play a video in the background of my flutter application
so I followed [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299162/video-background-in-flutter) and [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35caowA4EMc).

I came up with the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoWidget());

class VideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoWidgetState createState() => _VideoWidgetState();
}

class _VideoWidgetState extends State<VideoWidget> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("images/background.mov")
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _controller.setLooping(true);
        _controller.play();
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: _controller.value.initialized
          ? AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            )
          : Container(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

I made sure the video was available in the [images folder](https://i.gyazo.com/98fcb6e1e1d6ab9e130138ee1d052f25.png) and on the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  hovering: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  video_player: ^0.10.5+2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/2x/IconWithText.png
    - images/IconWithText.png
    - images/background.mov
```

But after building the application i end up with the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
#0      VideoPlayerApi.create (package:video_player_platform_interface/messages.dart:199:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelVideoPlayer.create (package:video_player_platform_interface/method_channel_video_player.dart:46:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      VideoPlayerController.initialize (package:video_player/video_player.dart:275:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _VideoWidgetState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:myapp/video_widget.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

And i call VideoWidget like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var isLogged = false;
    var column = Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        VideoWidget(),
        Table(
```

I'm a beginner to dart and flutter so make sure to ask me if you need more information to help to resolve this issue and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

run the application again. Some time plugins don't work without closing the app and running it again.

Comment: If you are on Windows, stop the running app and run this in the terminal `flutter clean; flutter pub get` and then run the app again and it will start working.

Answer (score 3):

from your dependencies, your version was to old, try to upgrade it first to 1.0.1 because your error it seems from your dependencies

Comment: video_player: ^1.0.1 ?

Comment: i tried doing video_player: ^1.0.1 and then restart the application and i end up on the same issue.

Comment: video_player dependencies that you use has supported format video, please check it at this link https://exoplayer.dev/supported-formats.html because video_player use exoplayer as player

Comment: @iqbalrahardian thanks... turns out a .MOV file just recorded from iOS camera is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As said before completely running again the app (no hot reload nor restart) could solve your issue. If not try to clean the pod by doing so:

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install
```

In your terminal could be a solution aswell.