# "Unable to establish connection on channel" error while trying to play video using the video_player package

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-video-player

I'm using Flutter to develop a desktop app that is supposed to play a video in it and therefore I have added the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) flutter package to my pubspec.yaml file by adding the following:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  video_player: ^2.1.1
```

The following code is used build the widget:

```
class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Create an store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("videos/media.mp4");

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 450,
      width: 800,
      // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
      // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            _controller.play();
            // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
            // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
            return AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            );
          } else {
            // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
            // loading spinner.
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

However, it ended up with the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
```

I'm aware that the same question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214275/video-widget-doesnt-play-unable-to-establish-connection-on-channel) but the error there has been caused due to an unsupported .mov file and due to the use of an older version of the package both of which I have verified to be correct in my case.

Comment: Had same issue and simply with AndroidStudio -> Invalidate caches / restart + flutter clean works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter video_player plugin has yet to have desktop support. You can track this feature request on this [GitHub Issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37673).