# Issue with video_player : 2.2.19 package

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

Getting this error on release build for video player, but the debug build works fine
PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
I/flutter (13504): ------------StackTrace-------------
I/flutter (13504): #0      VideoPlayerApi.create (package:video_player_android/src/messages.dart:181)
I/flutter (13504): 
I/flutter (13504): #1      AndroidVideoPlayer.create (package:video_player_android/src/android_video_player.dart:56)
I/flutter (13504): 
I/flutter (13504): #2      VideoPlayerController.initialize (package:video_player/video_player.dart:352)
I/flutter (13504):

Tried :

- Flutter upgrade
- flutter pub --outdated

Comment: Check if any of these helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214275/video-widget-doesnt-play-unable-to-establish-connection-on-channel

Comment: @SahilSonawane Checked this but still no luck, Only facing issue with android, Also upgraded the video_player plugin to 2.4.7 the latest one

Comment: Have you tried running clean, pub get and run?

Comment: Yes @SahilSonawane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, Add this in MainActivity.kt file and then run the project

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.videoplayer.*





class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: 
 FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(SharedPreferencesPlugin())
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(VideoPlayerPlugin())

}
}
```