# Flutter video background player instead of image background

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video-player

Here is my issue, i am trying to achieve video background player instead og my image background i tried with gif but render is just in 256 colours. thanks very much I 'have been pulling my hair to integrate with no success

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget {
static const your_client_id = '0000000000000000';
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
static const your_redirect_url =
'https://xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler';

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    child: Scaffold(

  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  image: DecorationImage(
  image: AssetImage("asset/images/bg.jpg"),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  )
  ),
```

Trying to replace my container content with this code i dont know if its the right thing to do

```
Container(
 width: *screen width*,
 height: *screen height*,
 child: Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
     Center(
       child: Transform.scale(
         scale: 3.9, //change this number as needed
         AspectRatio(
           aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
           child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
         ),
       ),
     ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack` to have your video play in the background while in loop, while your other `widget` is at the top of the `stack`.

This person solved it please refer to his answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763089/8572736

Comment: I would i integrate in my code above? the rest of the code is a login process, thanks

Comment: sorry don't understand your question, can you explain more?

Comment: I mean in my container i would like to put the videoplayer but its not working got errors

Comment: can you share the errors? so I can help you debug the problem